# Move TFVC code from one collection to another including history

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I need to move some code from TFVC in one project collection to a project in another collection.   I also need to retain the check-in history,  I'm not worried about the changeset ids but do want to retain the comment / who and when in the history along with the changes made.   The project being moved to will be empty.

This will be using on premise TFS2017 Update 3.   (In preparation to migrating the collection to VSTS)

Any suggestions on how to do this please?

Answer (score 1):

There is a request for this feature in queue for long time but MSFT has not started implementing it yet, according to the request [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te).

I have used [TFS Integration platform](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=tfsintegration) with TFS 2013, which allowed me to move work items and source code with full history, from a team project to a different collection team project. Unfortunately this tool is deprecated now and no longer supported or developed for newer versions of TFS. But you can give it a trial run to see if it works for your purpose.

The tool [TFS sync migration](http://vsts-bulk-editor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) also does not support Source control migration, it only supports work items.