# TFS 2018: Set changeset author and date by REST API

Tags: c#, tfs

I have an on-prem TFS 2018 and trying to move a specific project from one project collection to another. As this is not supported by Microsoft (see User Voice suggestion [here](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/2037613-make-it-possible-to-move-a-team-project-between-te) and StackOverflow thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48518202/move-tfvc-code-from-one-collection-to-another-including-history) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100406/moving-a-team-project-from-one-collection-to-another)) and we need full control we decided to move the project programmatically using the REST API.

So I builded a small C#.NET application and included the [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/). Everything is working as expected and I'm able to replay the full history of the project in question to another project collection.

Unfortunately, I've problems to set changesets creation date and author. And I was not able to find a solution here or anywhere else.

When I set the CreationDate, the value will be overwritten with the current date by TFS:

```
TfvcChangeset changeset = new TfvcChangeset()
{
    Changes = changes.ToArray(),
    Comment = comment,
    CreatedDate = sourceChangeset.CreatedDate,
    //Author = sourceChangeset.Author,
    //CheckedInBy = sourceChangeset.CheckedInBy,
};

TfvcChangesetRef changesetRef = targetVersionControl.CreateChangesetAsync(changeset).Result;
// the resulting changeset reference now has current change date
```

The code is inspired by a [Microsoft sample at GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-dotnet-samples/blob/master/ClientLibrary/Snippets/Microsoft.TeamServices.Samples.Client/Tfvc/ChangesetsSample.cs).

When I either set Author or CheckedInBy (see code snippet above) an `ArgumentException` occurs at the call of `CreateChangesetAsync`:

```cs
ArgumentException: The combination of parameters is either not valid or not complete.
```

**(see update below)** In my case I just use the value from the source changeset, as both project collections (source and target) are part of the same TFS instance and therefore using the same identities from the TFS configuration database.

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/tfvc/changesets/create), I expect that setting both values should be possible, although the documentation is not very precise at all.

Additionally, I was not able to found a solution to update the changeset once it was checked in to TFS.

Note: I know that there is some existing software out there which targets moving project, but they're either outdated, not fully working (e.g. missing move of work items) or to black-boxed for our needs.

**Update:** My first thoughts about the reuse of the identity in different collections of the same TFS instance where not correct. Although identities are stored only in TFS configuration database (tbl_Identities), a local ID will be assigned to every used identity in a specific project collection (tbl_IdentityMap in the project collection's database). So I created a map of both tables to assign the target Identity ID instead of the source Identity ID. I tried to get the `IdentityRef` from the `IdentityHttpClient` but only get a `Identity` instance, so I create the `IdentityRef` manually. The exception mentioned above still occurs.

```cs
// _targetConnection is the VssConnection instance
var targetIdentities = _targetConnection.GetClient<IdentityHttpClient>();
var author = targetIdentities.ReadIdentityAsync(Guid.Parse(targetAuthorId)).Result;
changeset.Author = new IdentityRef()
{
    // some properties will remain default, as Identity does not contain
    Id = author.Id.ToString("D", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    DisplayName = author.DisplayName,
    //ImageUrl = author.Properties,
    //IsAadIdentity = author.IsAadIdentity,
    IsContainer = author.IsContainer,
    //ProfileUrl = author.ProfileUrl,
    //UniqueName = author..UniqueName,
    //Url = author.Url,
};
```

I also tried to create a `IdentityRef` from the source changeset's IdentityRef (with the local identity ID of the target project collection) without success (still same exception).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, it's not able to set/modify changeset author and date by REST API in TFS. It is also easy to understand. If a source control system is easily to change this area, 
it seems kind of violate the version control. And the changeset history will become no reference value, we do not know if the author and the date is the real one and time checked in.

This is also documented clearly in Microsoft Docs, please take a look at below part: [Using public API-based tools for higher fidelity migration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migrate-to-vsts-from-tfs?view=vsts#option-3-using-public-api-based-tools-for-higher-fidelity-migration) You are also using the API and kind of build your own tool.

> Generally these tools can provide a higher fidelity migration than a
>   manual copy of "tip" data, but they are still relatively low fidelity.
>   For example:
>
> - None of them will **preserve the dates of TFVC changesets.**
> - Many of them will not preserve the changed dates of work item    revisions.
> - None of them will migrate all TFS artifacts.

Comment: OK, I totally understood that you usually and in almost any case must not edit things like author, changeset date and so on.
However, I cannot imagine that there is no TFS admin out there who wants - or even needs - to reorganize team projects and team project collections in TFS. Splitting up according to Microsoft's docs - [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/admin/split-team-project-collection) - is helpful, but merging team project collections should by available as well (our project collections are very fragmented due to several aquisitions in the past).